# Rails starting in strange environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rbenv, puma

I have a very bizarre issue that suddenly popped up with my rails.

I've explicity set `RAILS_ENV` to `development`:

```
$ echo $RAILS_ENV
development
```

But when I run my apps, one of two things happens:

- They either run in development on port 3003, instead of 3000, and
- For a couple, they run in **production** on port 3003, and I cannot switch them to development no matter what I do.

This happens in pow, puma-dev, and using `rails s`.  I've tried explicitly setting `RAILS_ENV` in `.powenv`, `.pumaenv`, `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile`, `.config/fish/config.fish`, and `.rbenv-vars` (I'm using rbenv).

I've also tried changing ruby versions, to no avail.

I uninstalled and reinstalled Pow, after wiping launcher scripts, and then, after I got frustrated, switched to puma-dev..  But, again, the same thing happens in `rails s` and **even when I use `bundle exec rails s -e development`**!

Anyone know where else to look?  I can't develop with the apps running in production~

Answer (score 1):

i think you can check `config/puma.rb` which contains in my case

```
threads_count = ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 }
threads threads_count, threads_count
port        ENV.fetch("PORT") { 3000 }
environment ENV.fetch("RAILS_ENV") { "development" }
plugin :tmp_restart
```

(other lines are commented)

Answer (score 1):

So, obviously, the answer was something obvious.  I had an errant `.rbenv-vars` in my home folder.  I'd downloaded it from a server and forgot about it.

I found it by running `grep -in "3003" ~/.*` (after a whole bunch of other similar commands).